# how to write site_url link in json

Tags: json, codeigniter

I want to create a site_url codeigniter link to call the controller in json, how to write correctly?

really need help.

```
function tampil_data_customer(){
  $.ajax({
    type : 'ajax',
    url : '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/selling_process/all_customer',
    async : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){             
        var html = '';
        var j=1;
        for(i=0; i< data.length; i++){  
            html += '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+j+++'</td>'+
                    '<td><a href="<?php site_url('selling_process/view/'); ?>"'+data[i].id_customer+'>'+data[i].name_customer+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_customer_type+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_sector+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_user+'</td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_status+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].update_date+'</td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '</tr>';
        }
        $('.show_data').html(html);
    }
  });
}
```

this part is not working

```
'<td><a href="<?php site_url('selling_process/view/'); ?>"'+data[i].id_customer+'>'+data[i].name_customer+'</a></td>'+
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
'<td><a href="' + '<?php echo site_url('selling_process/view/'); ?>' + data[i].id_customer+'">'+data[i].name_customer+'</a></td>'+
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it. Especially, I'd like to know why you put opening PHP tags in the `href` attribute

Comment: Using javascript In php file, you can put php tag and use "echo" to get the value of php variable in javascript. So, as the code above, href attribute shown in browser will be example.com/selling_process/view/1

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that would be using JavaScript. You can get the base URL of your site then append the required URL to it.

To get the base url in JS,

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var pathparts = location.pathname.split('/');
    if (location.host == 'localhost' || location.host == '127.0.0.1' || location.host == '::1') {
        var url = location.origin + '/' + pathparts[1].trim('/') + '/'; // http://localhost/myproject/
    }else{
        var url = location.origin + '/';
    }
    return url;
}
```

After that, you can use this function to get the base URL in your HTML/JS file like this,

```
function tampil_data_customer(){
  $.ajax({
    type : 'ajax',
    url : '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/selling_process/all_customer',
    async : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){             
        var html = '';
        var j=1;
        for(i=0; i< data.length; i++){  
            html += '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+j+++'</td>'+
                    `<td><a href=${getBaseUrl() + 'selling_process/view/'}`+data[i].id_customer+'>'+data[i].name_customer+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_customer_type+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_sector+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_user+'</td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].name_status+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+data[i].update_date+'</td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '<td></td>'+
                    '</tr>';
        }
        $('.show_data').html(html);
    }
  });
}
```